# A button behind svg

Tags: html, css, svg

In a html document, I have an svg image I have a button behind. The svg has a hole, so I can see the button but I cannot click it. Why does it happen and how can I click to that div (in this case #blue)

Here is how I see it in html (green is the svg, blue a div I added in html):

[image: Here is how I see it in html]

(I opened the svg with Inkscape and I am sure that there is a hole, not only transparent. For different reasons the button must be behind, I cannot put it on top)

```
#blue {
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px; left: 150px;
    width:200px; height: 200px;
    font-size:16px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:blue;
    z-index: 0;
}

#green {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

<div id="blue"></div>
<img id="green" src="1.svg">
```

Comment: can you produce a complete code with the SVG also

Comment: Why don't you put the div in front.

Comment: does the div only have to be behind in the source order? can't you swap the z index on the 2 objects?

Comment: _“Why does it happen ”_ - because what you think it a “hole” isn’t actually one ...

Comment: @Bhuwan for design reasons. What I show here is very simplified

Comment: @Temani The real svg is very complicated It would be difficult to produce the code in the html

Comment: @synj green must be on top of blue in this example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear whether you want the entire SVG to let clicks through, or just the hole.

If you are okay with the SVG `<img>` being completely invisible to clicks, then just set `pointer-events="none";`.

```
#green {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: In fact I need only the hole to let clicks through. Anyway, this is a fantastic option I did not know!. So simple.

Answer (score 2):

I guess svg will always behave as a rectangular element even if there is hole or transparent element. I think you should try clip-path to create the hole and be able to click the behind link:

```css
#blue {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 0;
}

#blue:hover {
  background: red;
}

#green {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 25% 100%, 25% 25%, 75% 25%, 75% 75%, 22% 75%, 23% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 25% 100%, 25% 25%, 75% 25%, 75% 75%, 22% 75%, 23% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
}
```

```html
<div id="blue"></div>
<svg width="200" height="200" id="green">
  <rect width="200" height="200" style="fill:green;" />
</svg>
```

And you can also do this without svg:

```css
#blue {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 0;
}

#blue:hover {
  background: red;
}

#green {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background:green;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 25% 100%, 25% 25%, 75% 25%, 75% 75%, 22% 75%, 23% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 25% 100%, 25% 25%, 75% 25%, 75% 75%, 22% 75%, 23% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
}
```

```html
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
```

Comment: Interesting solution. It works well in a simple shape. You must be aware that I simplified the case, just to explain it here. In a real scenario and complex shapes it must be really difficult. Has that solution any advantage over putting the svg code directly in the html?

Comment: @Nrc yes of course, for complex shape it's more difficult :) But this solution doesn't require to put SVG in the site (simply put an example), it also doesn't require SVG, it can work with any element ... the main idea is to reproduce the hole using clip-path as you can see in my second solution, where i used a simple quare and create the hole

Comment: @Nrc so i guess even with complex shape you can find a way to create path, and you can aslo use some tools like this website https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/